# Selecting nested DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select a nested `HTML` element with `jQuery`.

```
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
    <div class="events_box">
      <div class="event_left">
        <div class="event_left-item">
          <div class="icon_2">
            <i class="fa fa-clock-o" id="programHoursId0"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="icon_2">
            <i class="fa fa-location-arrow" id="programLocationId0"></i>
          </div>
```

I have to select the classes `fa fa-clock-o` and `fa fa-location-arrow`. I am able to select them by ID but I want select them by class.
I already have tried combinations like:

```
 $('div div div .fa fa-clock-o').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

And:

```
 $('.event_left .event_left-item .icon_2 .fa fa-clock-o').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

And:

```
 $('div.fa fa-clock-o').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

Along with many more....

The goal is to hide those FontAwesome icons.

Comment: you are missing a dot in your selector `.fa-clock-o`

Comment: `$('.fa-clock-o').hide()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `fa` and `fa-clock-o` are classes on the same element you must not have space between them in the selector or jQuery (or any alternative like `querySelector`) will think one is a descendant of the other. Try this:

```
$('.fa.fa-clock-o')
//   ^^^
```

`div.fa fa-clock-o`: look for any descendant of type `fa-clock-o` (tag) of a `div` that has the class `fa` => nothing selected because there is no tag `fa-clock-o`.

`div.fa .fa-clock-o`: look for any elements with the class `fa-clock-o` that are descendants of a `div` with the class `fa` => will match what you want.

`.fa.fa-clock-o`: look for elements that have the classes `fa` and `fa-clock-o` => matches what you want too

Comment: Should be `$('i.fa.fa-clock-o')` or `$('div .fa.fa-clock-o')`. The `div` element is the parent . . . the `i` element has the "fa" classes on it.

Comment: @talemyn yeah I was editing when you commented! After you edited the qustion and the indentaion of the code, I noticed I had that mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this `$('.fa').hide();`

Comment: Wow tnx for the fast response!. @artemisian .fa is hide all the elements that start with fa. Rly good guess. I`m gonna accept the answer that has been provided by @ibrahim mahrir because since he is right about fa and fa-clock-o are separated classes. The selector was $('.fa-clock-o').

Comment: Hi @NDym, it was not a guess, in your answer you mentioned that `I have to select the classes fa fa-clock-o and fa fa-location-arrow.` and that `The goal is to hide those FontAwesome icons` so that class selector will select all those FontAwesome icons.